# use a value in an array to create another array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, loops, matrix

My problem is:
I have generated an array of values as:

```
bias=numpy.random.normal(0.0, 1.0, size=50)
```

so there are 50 values in the array bias. And I want to use each of them to generate another 50 arrays:

for example:

```
XX[i]=truncnorm.rvs(lower, upper, bias[i], sig, size=50)
```

I know I have to define the XX and the notations above to get the new arrays may not be correct (e.g., the index). Also, I need to loop on each value of the array bias to get the new arrays: XX[0], ..., XX[49].

I know how to do this in Matlab but have difficulties in doing this loop in Python.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To create a list of arrays your can use:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

bias = np.random.normal(0.0, 1.0, size=50)

XX = []  # empty list

for value in bias:  # for-loop
    # append a new array to the list in every loop
    XX.append(stats.truncnorm.rvs(0, 1, value, 1, size=50))
```

Read more on for-loops here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop